# Public XML URLs

Tags: xml, url, web

Does anybody know of any public sites on the net that have URLs with a ".xml" extension?

Need XML URLs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress's URLs have an XML extension.  For example: http://devexpress.com/Home/Announces/2010-1-silverlight-controls.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Basically every page of the http://www.wowarmory.com